# Turning off TeXnical enhancements

Tags: fontspec, typography, ligatures, kerning

I want to create a table for comparing TeX's typography with that of (approximated) other document solutions.  I'd like to turn off *all* TeXnical enhancements for a single column of text—no ligatures, no good kerning, etc.  I'm trying to use `fontspec` to do this, since Computer Modern simply doesn't have the ligatures I'm also looking to show off (`fj` for example).

Since the solution doesn't particularly ride on being usable in a table (to my knowledge), any solution where such typography is turned off within a group would work. :-)

Here is my attempt at a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,booktabs,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
{
  \setmainfont{Hoefler Text} % Linux Libertine also has fj I believe,
                             % but I do not have it installed on my system
  \begin{tabular}{ c >{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=NoCommon}}c }
    \toprule
    \TeX & \MicrosoftWord \\
    \midrule
    Table & T{}a{}b{}l{}e \\
    SALT  & S{}A{}L{}T    \\
    AVAST & A{}V{}A{}S{}T \\
    \midrule
    efficient firefly & e{}f{}f{}i{}c{}i{}e{}n{}t f{}i{}r{}e{}f{}l{}y \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
  \caption{A comparison of \TeX\ and other word processing solutions
    (such as \MicrosoftWord) in regards to
    kerning, ligatures, and small capitals}
  \label{tab:compare}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which does successfully turn off ligatures, but I've *no* idea how to 'turn off' kerning other than what I'm doing right now, which is very much not in the spirit of TeX (one that I am actively trying to advertise).

Comment: Or you could show them [this xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/1015/) `:)`.

Comment: @Christoph [Waaaay ahead of you](https://github.com/vermiculus/smcm-tex/blob/04df2e19ffc879b1e636978605dea7bdc0ee543b/why-tex/typography.tex#L93) `;-)`

Comment: (rather, [line 55](https://github.com/vermiculus/smcm-tex/blob/04df2e19ffc879b1e636978605dea7bdc0ee543b/why-tex/typography.tex#L55).  Whoops.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dangit, should have looked closer at the manual.

If the font is OpenType, you can turn kerning on and off as well with a simple `Kerning=(on|off)` switch:

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
{
  \setmainfont{Corbel}
  \begin{tabular}{ c >{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=NoCommon,Kerning=Off}}c }
    \toprule
    \TeX & \MicrosoftWord \\
    \midrule
    Table & Table \\
    SALT  & SALT    \\
    AVAST & AVAST \\
    \midrule
    efficient firefly & efficient firefly \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
  \caption{A comparison of \TeX\ and other word processing solutions
    (such as \MicrosoftWord) in regards to
    kerning, ligatures, and small capitals}
  \label{tab:compare}
\end{table}
```

The trick now is finding an OTF that looks nice with the rest of my document.
Anyway, hope this helps anybody else who might be looking for such a thing!

Comment: An off-topic hint on making your code more reader- and debug-friendly: Since you're (presumably) still loading the `array` package, you could issue the command `\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=NoCommon,Kerning=Off}}c}` in the preamble and then type `\begin{tabular}{cZ}` later on.

Comment: @Mico Tip taken and very much appreciated! Makes the actual tabular-spec a lot cleaner.